# В какую папку устанавливать ember-cli в symfony 3.1

Tags: symfony3, ember.js

В какую папку устанавливать ember-cli в symfony 3.1 и как все это дело настроить грамотно и удобно. Т.е. максимум автоматизации(компиляция less,деплой и тд и тп ).Хотя бы ссылочку киньте на актуальную информацию, пожалуйста!!=)

Answer (score 1):

- Посмотрите в сторону [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)'а. Это task-менеджер, который может выполнять всякие задачки связанные с frontend частью и не только.
- Для подгрузки всех необходимых зависимостей воспользуйтесь возможностями npm, а именно создайте файл `package.json`, в котором укажете все зависимости (может быть есть более хороший способ, стоит поискать).
- Если вы хотите автоматизировать это при разливе, вы можете обратиться к `composer`'у, а именно к его директиве `scripts`, например в SF3:

  ```
  "scripts": {
      "post-install-cmd": [
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets"
      ],
      "post-update-cmd": [
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets"
      ]
  },
  ```